# Filtering the $allowedtags global in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to filter the `$allowedtags` global in WordPress so that users can submit certain HTML elements only in comments.

This is how I'm currently doing it:

```
function my_allowed_tags() {
    global $allowedtags;
    $allowedtags['pre'] = array( 'style' => array() );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_allowed_tags' );
```

This now allows the use of `<pre>` tags in comments along with a default list of tags that are already allowed by `$allowedtags` such as `<p>`, `<a>`, `<img>` etc.

How can I initialise the `$allowedtags` global so that no tags are allowed by default?

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables#Admin_Globals

Comment: add a filter on init, before your current one which sets `$allowedtags = array();` which will remove all the already set ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a filter which resets the global to an empty array before your current action fires.

```
function reset_allowed_tags() {
    global $allowedtags;
    $allowedtags = array();
}
add_action('init', 'reset_allowed_tags', 0);
```

Comment: Of course! I think I had the developer version of writer's block when I wrote the question. Thanks for your help :)